# AWS | Using DynamoDB results in "ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Im trying to utilize AWS JS SDK in my Angular application.

Consider the following code:

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

declare let AWSCognito: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  private _dynamodb;

  constructor() {
    AWS.config.region = 'eu-west-2'; // Region
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
      IdentityPoolId: 'eu-west-2:xxyyzz'
    });
    this._dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._dynamodb.get({TableName: 'somename', Key: {projectId: 123321}}, (err, data) => {
    })
  }
}
```

When the above code is executed the following error appears:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

I can see that it's `this._dynamodb.get` that makes the system crash.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

Full stack trace:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at hasOwnProperty (<anonymous>)
    at isEndpointDiscoveryApplicable (discover_endpoint.js:279)
    at Request.discoverEndpoint (discover_endpoint.js:322)
    at Request.callListeners (sequential_executor.js:102)
    at Request.emit (sequential_executor.js:78)
    at Request.emit (request.js:683)
    at Request.transition (request.js:22)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (state_machine.js:14)
    at state_machine.js:26
    at Request.<anonymous> (request.js:38)
```

Comment: If you add logging of this._dynamodb to the constructor after initializing _dynamodb and in the ngOnInit() method before invoking get(), does it provide any clues?

Comment: @jarmod it provides no clues. I can console log the pointer to the function (console.log(this._dynamodb.get)) just above the function call

Comment: For what it's worth, a simplified version of this code (no Angular, no classes) getting Key: { projectId: 123321 } using the DocumentClient works just fine for me. Are you using up to date AWS SDK? Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: See edit. I have other projects where similar code works just fine. I think it something to do with a upgrade in a node_module, but Im not sure. 
On think I really hate with Angular is how a project can break apart when a single node component is upgraded, it can be a real struggle to solve

Comment: I don't see the get call in the stack trace. Are you sure that the this._dynamodb.get() call is the culprit?

Comment: @jarmod yes, I’m sure that’s where the error I triggered.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/2347